# Linking error when invoking the F# Compiler (FSC) directly

Tags: f#

I am trying to understand the F# compilation process by directly calling FSC.

I want to:

- Download the SDK
- Unpack it to a local folder
- Invoke FSC on a few F# source-files
- Output a standalone Linux executable

Here is my script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

SDK_URL="https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/820db713-c9a5-466e-b72a-16f2f5ed00e2/628aa2a75f6aa270e77f4a83b3742fb8/dotnet-sdk-5.0.100-linux-x64.tar.gz"
SDK=./dotnet_sdk

if [ ! -d $SDK ]
then
  echo "Fetching SDK... "
  wget -c $SDK_URL

  echo "Unpacking SDK... "
  mkdir -p $SDK
  tar -xzf ./dotnet-sdk-5.0.100-linux-x64.tar.gz --directory $SDK
fi

$SDK/dotnet $SDK/sdk/5.0.100/FSharp/fsc.exe \
  -I $SDK/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/5.0.0 \
  --targetprofile:netcore \
  --deterministic \
  --noframework \
  --standalone \
  --target:exe \
  --out:hello.exe \
  ./Hello.fs
```

And my program `Hello.fs`:

```ml
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  printfn "Hello, world. "
  0
```

But when I run the script I get this error:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 11.0.0.0 for F# 5.0 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved. 
error FS2008: Static linking may not include a mixed managed/unmanaged DLL
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this error. It means that you're trying to [link an assembly that's not pure IL](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/b23b2a0f99f12ece94c5ad89aabb9169d51091f3/src/fsharp/StaticLinking.fs#L115), but I don't know which one. I think there's some conflict between `standalone` and the `netcore` profile. Support for this seems [fairly new](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/3924). FWIW, I don't get the same error when I use the `netstandard` profile instead, or when I use `netcore` with `standalone` on Windows.

Comment: @brianberns Thanks. If I don't build with `--standalone` then how do I generate the `runtimeconfig.json` file?

Comment: Using the `netcore` profile gives you the `runtimeconfig.json` file, right? Assuming that's important (especially since you're on Linux), perhaps you can do without `--standalone`?

Comment: `--targetprofile:netcore` without `--standalone` still does not produce a `runtimeconfig.json` for me

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about running the compiler directly to answer. Would you consider creating a `.fsproj` file instead? Then you can just run `dotnet build` and it will definitely create a `runtimeconfig.json` file.

Comment: One more idea: With a `.fsproj` file, you can run `dotnet build` with verbosity turned on (`-v n`) to see the compiler flags that it uses. You could then probably invoke the compiler directly with the same flags if you want.